# SPI通信に関する初歩的な質問

Tags: spresense

spresenseに関する初歩的な質問です。拡張ボードを使ってSPI通信する確認を行っています。
menuconfigでSPIを有効にしました。

CXD56xx Configuration  --->

[*] SPI

[*] SPI4

nshで/devを確認したところ特に変化は見られなかったのですが、SPI4を使用する準備はこれ以外に何か必要なのでしょうか？

Comment: 環境はなんでしょうか。

Comment: spresense v1.4.0です。公式のSpresense SDK 開発ガイドに沿って"hello" Exampleを入れた状態で、tools/config.py -mでSPIの設定を変更しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NuttX の Driver Model では、一般的に i2c, spi のような bus driver をそのまま "/dev" に出すのではなく、実際に SPI 通信を使用する「物理センサーデバイス」側のドライバで、"/dev/センサ" という /devインタフェースを作成します。

具体例として、SPI を使った3軸ジャイロセンサ L3GD20 のドライバがこちらにあります。
https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-nuttx/blob/master/drivers/sensors/l3gd20.c

```
int l3gd20_register(FAR const char *devpath, FAR struct spi_dev_s *spi,
                    FAR struct l3gd20_config_s *config)
```

このドライバの登録関数が "devpath" で渡された /dev を作成して、 open, close, read, write, ioctlといった POSIX インターフェースを提供しています。実体は、引数に渡された spi_dev_s を通して、このドライバ内部で SPI_XXX() を使用して SPI 通信を行っています。

これは Spresense SDK の場合でも同じ構成になっていると思います。

以下に、BMI160 SPI の例を見つけました。
https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense/blob/master/sdk/bsp/board/common/src/cxd56_bmi160_spi.c

```
  spi = cxd56_spibus_initialize(bus);
  ret = bmi160_register("/dev/accel0", spi);
```

1. cxd56_spibus_initialize(bus) に SPI 番号を渡してSPIを初期化した後に
2. その spi と "/dev/accel0" という名前で bmi160 ドライバに渡しています。

ですので、回答としては、SPI4 を使用する Configuration としては合っているけど、それだけで /dev/spi が作成されるわけではないので、実際に SPI で通信するドライバを登録してはじめて "/dev/xxx" が作られるということになるかと思います。

Comment: と回答しましたが、一応、補足しておくと、NuttX 本家には、https://bitbucket.org/nuttx/apps/src/master/system/spi/README.txt に直接 /dev/spiX を作成する SPI Toolというものもあったりします。I2C Toolの方は、Spresense SDKにも取り込まれているようです。